# Setting up home wireless network

Tags: wifi, wireless, networking, router

I'm trying to set up wireless network at my home. I've been given a router Zyxel Keentic Extra for my birthday as I didn't have any. It looks like this router isn't enough to cover all my flat. It has kind of unsuitable layout for Wi-Fi including thick wall in the middle that cuts down more then a half of the signal.
I think there're two possibilities (which are basically the same): either I need to buy/make repeater for my Zyxel or get something ready like Netgear Orbi.
What hardware should I use for extending Wi-Fi network? Is there any routers with "super powerful" antennas, so it would be able to deliver good signal in problem spots?
Here's my flat [image: layout]

Comment: Ubiquiti's Access Points (APs) which essentially provide access to a wired network with wifi have an _excellent_ reputation when it comes to signal strength (of course they are a bit pricey, but probably cheaper than the orbi).

Comment: @SEJPM thanks for the advice! I googled Ubiquity products. It looks like APs use PoE technology and also lack of Ethernet ports which is not suitable in my situation (I can use it neither as gateway to my network nor as AP). Is there any solutions for APs to do "conversations" with router in a wireless way? (That's what Orbi is able to offer) It would be even better to have seamless connection between router AP and repeater AP. Or just wifi router (to make it network gateway) with Ubiquity's quality and a bit more ports.

Comment: I had a look and it appears that if you have two Ubiquiti APs, you _can_ set one up as a repeater of the other and just feed power to it (this is called "Wireless Uplink" in Ubiquiti-Marketing-Language). If you search for something like "ubquiti ap repeater" you should find a description. As for the power supply, if you look around on your favourite shopping plattform there should be "poe injector"s which convert wall power to PoE for the repeating AP.

Comment: @SEJPM Yes, I found it. But the remaining problem with ports shortfall. So it looks like I need switch and/or gateway (UniFi Security Gateway, USG) before the first AP. I saw Pro version of Ubiquity AC AP, it has only 1 WAN, 1 LAN and 1 USB port. This might be really close to what I need.